# Remove Screen is pinned popup

Tags: android, locking, screen, handle, mode

I'm using Activity.startLockTask() for lock my app, but when I start startLockTask(), it showed popup like under.
I tried solution:

- Use accessibility for handle Got it button, and perform a click on it
- Use accessibility and handlle click on center position of screen.

But accessibility can't handle it, accessibility doesn't detect there popup.
Who are know any solution? Please let me know. Thanks all.

[image]